# PHP/WordPress -- How do I check if Shortcode returns content?

Tags: shortcode, plugin-ninja-forms

What I'm basically trying to do is check if a shortcode is returning any content, I'm using a plugin called [Ninja forms](http://ninjaforms.com) and they have default content posting using their own shortcodes which look like this:

```
[ninja_forms_field id=84]
```

Assuming it works like a WordPress's default shortcode, how would I check if it returns any content, I've been trying to get this basic PHP code to work but it doesn't seem to ever evaluate as true:

```
<?php
if(!empty([ninja_forms_field id=84])){
    echo "has content";
} else{
    echo "not working";
}
```

I'm using a WP plugin called "Insert PHP" to run PHP in the default post form, I did several test and this plugin runs PHP wonderfully, so it's the shortcode logic that's failing me.

Here's a quick Ninja Forms [article](http://docs.ninjaforms.com/customer/portal/articles/2042238-post-creation#post_creation_default_content) on their Shortcodes, this might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run the Shortcode through [`do_shortcode`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) and check what the output contains.

```
$shortcode_content = do_shortcode( '[ninja_forms_field id=84]' );
```